# Xpages: "Invalid component id null for partial execution"

Tags: java, xpages, renderer

I'd really like to find in which component it's getting stuck. The first few lines of the Stack Trace are:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Invalid component id null for partial execution
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.EventHandlerRenderer.appendSubmitJS(EventHandlerRenderer.java:211)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.EventHandlerRenderer.processHandlers(EventHandlerRenderer.java:151)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.EventHandlerRenderer.encodeBegin(EventHandlerRenderer.java:86)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UICommandEx2.encodeBegin(UICommandEx2.java:395)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.encodeBegin(UIEventHandler.java:329)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:841)
```

There are too many components on the page to test them one by one, so a more general approach would be better. A more or less simple solution could be to extend a class and make it display some more info when there's an error, like this:

```
package com.acme;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class EventHandlerRenderer extends com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.EventHandlerRenderer {
  public void encodeBegin(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1) throws IOException  {
    try {
        System.out.print("encoding " + arg1.getId());
        super.encodeBegin(arg0, arg1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Or maybe do that for the UIComponentBase class, if possible. Problem is: I don't know how to enable it in faces-config.xml.

Could anyone tell me how I can get some indication about which component causes this error?  Thanks.

Comment: Does the domino/workspace/logs/trace-log-*.xml or domino/workspace/logs/error-log-*.xml files perhaps contain info on the component?

Comment: Nope :-( . I use the logreader database, and assuming it shows me the trace and error log information available, there's no more info.

Comment: I changed some of my code and this issue seems to be solved, although I don't quite understand why.  And I still would like to make the message more helpful, in this case and maybe many other cases. I'll leave it open for the time being. Thanks Per!